# Synchronization of mail servers

Tags: email, server, postfix-mta, dovecot, roundcube

There are 2 mail servers, one of which was set up by the hosting provider and we use it as the main one, and we set up the second one with a similar interface (Roundcube) ourselves. They have exactly the same mailboxes created on them, they both work fine, but now, because the MX record of the first one has a higher priority, all the mail goes to it. I need mail to come to mailboxes, for example admin@example.com, which are on two servers, at the same time, and not, as now, only to the one with a higher priority. How can I synchronize these servers? (I used nginx, postfix, dovecot, postfixadmin, roundcube for mine)

Maybe Rsinc can help me? But I do not have full access to the server that the hosting provider set up for us, but I can connect to it via SSH with the help of a user with limited rights.

Comment: Why do you even keep the 2nd mail server instead of having everything go to the first one? Can't the other mail server just forward / relay everything to the main one?